# How to get the dropdown selected value inside the table that is in grid format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-table

```
<script language="javascript">
function get_ver() {
         var ver = $("#OSVER option:selected" ).text();
         alert ('valllllllllis' + ver);
}
</script>

print "<table width=100% cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=5 border=1 bordercolor='#006600' height=20 valign=top >";
print "<tr><td><h3>User Created BaaS Profiles</h3>";

print "</td></tr>";


while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$pol_type=$row['3'];
$pol_id=$row['0'];
$account_id=$row['2'];
$pol_ver=$row['pol_ver'];
$create_date=$row['create_date'];
$modifiy_date=$row['modifiy_date'];
if($uid == "1")
{
$sq="select * from baas_account where id=".$account_id;
}
else
{
$sq="select * from baas_account where id=" . $account_id . " and user_id=" .$uid;
}
$q=mysql_query($sq);
$row1=mysql_fetch_row($q);
$user_id=$row['user_id'];
$policy_name=$row1['2'];
$CSSUBS=$row['CSSUBS'];
$CSWKLYday=$row['CSWKLYday'];
$CSMNTday=$row['CSMNTday'];

//print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='direct_submit.php' method='post' onSubmit='return validate();'>";
print "<tr id='info' name='info'>";

//print "<td><input type='radio' name='profile_select' value='$pol_id' /></td>";


{
print "<td><a href='index.php?xtype=user_admin'>$user_id</a></td>";
}

print "<td>";
//print "<p>$policy_name</p>";
print "<div class='texthv'>";
print "<a href='dnd.php?pid=$pol_id'>$policy_name</a>";
if($pol_type=='baseline') { print " "; }
else {
//print "<div class='texthv'>";
print "</br><b><a href='dnd.php?pid=$pol_id' class='texthidevisi'>View |</a></b>

<b><a href='index.php?xtype=create_policy&pol_id=$pol_id&pol_type=$pol_type&os_ver=b'  class='texthidevisi' >Edit |</a></b>

<b><a href='index.php?pid=$pol_id&acc_id=$account_id&xtype=rename'  class='texthidevisi'>Rename |</a></b>

<b><a href='index.php?pid=$pol_id&acc_id=$account_id&xtype=delete_file'  class='texthidevisi'>Delete</a></b>
 ";
print "</div>";
}

print "</td>";

print "<td id='VER' name='VER'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select id='OSVER' name='OSVER' onchange='get_ver();'>";
if($uid == "1")
{
$sql_pol_ver=mysql_query("select pol_ver from baas_profile where id=".$pol_id);
}
else
{
$sql_pol_ver=mysql_query("select pol_ver from baas_profile where user_id= " . $uid . " and id=" .$pol_id);
}
print "<option value=$pol_ver>$pol_ver</option>";

$pol_ver_arch=mysql_query("select pol_ver from baas_archive where user_id= " . $uid . " and id=" . $pol_id . " ORDER BY pol_ver DESC");

pol_ver_arch))
{
$pol_ver_old=$row['pol_ver'];
print "<option value=$pol_ver>$pol_ver_old</option>";
}
print "</select></td>";

if($pol_type=='baseline')
{
        print "<td>CSC Baseline</td>";
} else{
        $final_create_date = date("n/j/y H:i:s", $create_date);
        $final_modifiy_date = date("n/j/y H:i:s", $modifiy_date);
        print "<td> $final_create_date  |  $final_modifiy_date</td>";
}

print "</table>";
print "</td>";
print "</tr>";
```

I want get the select value of dropdown box whose id='OSVER' which is inside the table. AS of now, I am able to get only the selected value of the first row but not the subsequent rows. Can anyone help here?

Comment: do u want to get the selected value of a dropdown using jquery..??

Comment: function get_ver() {
         var ver = $("#OSVER option:selected" ).text();
         alert ('valllllllllis' + ver);
}

Comment: wer are u calling this `get_ver()`,and it would be better if u update the question rather than pasting the code as comment

Comment: I am calling it onchange of dropbox whith ID=OSVER..  The line is -------  print "<td id='VER' name='VER'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select id='OSVER' name='OSVER' onchange='get_ver();'>";                                ---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your script with

```
<script>
    function get_ver(el) {
     var ver = $(el).closest("tr").find("option:selected").val();
     alert(ver)
     return false;
    }
</script>
```

and also your

`onchange='get_ver();'`

to

`onchange='get_ver(this);'`

When a function executes, it gets the this property—a variable with the value of the object that invokes the function where this is used.In your case you haven't passed this variable.Hope that helps u mate.. :)

**FYI**

ID's are single use and are only applied to one element.They are used to identify a single element.In your case u have an id named `OSVER` that is not unique.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p3kubbtz/)

Comment: Thanks Outlooker, there is a porblem like, the value its displaying is the first value of the dropbox and not the selected value.. For example if  the dropdown has values "3,2,1".. Even when select "1" , the alert is showing "3" as the selected value.

Comment: Thanks Outlooker!!!..Still facing the same problem...Not sure whats the problem..

Comment: there is no way you could go wrong doing this mate..Haven't u checked the fiddle

Comment: Solved!!!....It was variable mistake in the dropdown box. I dint pass the old values in the value tag of drop down, so it was not taking these old values.... Thanks again Outlooker...Ur coding was awesome!!!